# Why do I need to call yyterminate in the action for end-of-file?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I created a very simple lexer that counts the number of lines in the input. See below. Notice that when end-of-file is encountered, the count is output. Also, notice that `yyterminate()` is called. I found that if I don't call `yyterminate()`, the output contains the line count repeated over and over. Why do I need to call `yyterminate()`?

```
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%% 
.           { }
\n          { }
<<EOF>>     { fprintf(stdout, "%d", yylineno); yyterminate(); }
%%
int main()
{ yylex(); }
```

Comment: Because the lexer continues until an action `return`s something. `<<EOF>>` rules should normally `return 0`, unless they arrange for there to be more data available.

Comment: @rici You mean that if there is no return (or no yyterminate) in the action for <<EOF>>, then the lexer simply processes the input all over again?

Comment: No, I mean that it continues to loop. If you don't reset the input buffer, it will continue to match the `<<EOF>>` rule. But you could do something else, like change `yyin` to a different file, or create a string buffer, or just `unput`, or change to a different start condition in order to execute its `<<EOF>>` rule. If you don't do any of those things and you don't `return`, you've got an infinite loop.